# How to use existing database in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I've created SQLite database and I want to open and use it in xamarin,developing in CrossPlatform.
In android studio,I was using SQLiteOpenHelper to access to the database.
I want to know if there is a way to it in Xamarin.forms

Comment: read the docs - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: @Jason yes.But the info there is only about how to create database,how to add,delete,get item from it.I don't want  to create database and it's items in the code.I just want to open and read it

Comment: Is your database a SQLite database file? If so, then it's just a matter of following the docs and specifying the filename for that existing database file. If it isn't a SQLite database file, then add some more details to your question.

Comment: Yes, I've created it with DB browser for SQLite and is .db file. I also wonder,where to save(put) this db in my project.

Comment: The docs specify on the page previously linked by Jason where the documents folder is on each platform. You can save to that location.